# Dog Adoption Vocab

Tags: words

One of the joys of taking my dog for a walk here in Japan is the wealth of opportunities for small talk with my fellow dog walkers.  However, I find I'm lacking on puppy vocabulary....

この子は神経質【しんけいしつ】なんです。まだ日本に慣【な】れていません。
My boy is very skittish around new people and I have been using this as my explanation for why he doesn't want pets.  It's it sensical?

Also,seeing how most dogs in Japan are from pet shops, how would I explain that he is a rescue dog? I've seen 里親【さとおや】used online to reference a person who adopts a dog, but how do I reference the dog?

Thanks!

Comment: As the talks between us dog owners are often pretty colloquial, I would certainly vote for the 捨て犬　or この犬はもともとすてられた。But, I personally do not often point out the fact [that my 2 dogs are rescue dogs] to the people here, since many people who get their dogs from a pet shop, love them just as much and treat them just as well and at least many of us with rescue dogs, and I think that there is a risk that people think you are bragging about yourself if [at least without being asked] stressing yours are rescue dogs. Although I would like to stop "puppies for sale" being kept in pet shops in Japan!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> この子は神経質なんです。 ... My boy is very skittish around new people and I have been using this as my explanation for why he doesn't want pets.

makes sense to me, but I'd say more like:

> 「すみません、この子、[[人見知]{ひとみし}り](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BA%BA%E8%A6%8B%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%8A/)なもので・・・ (＾＾;)」

---

> まだ日本に慣れていません。

Do you mean your dog is not accustomed to Japanese people? 外国で生まれ育って、日本に来てからあまり時間が経っていないから、日本人に慣れていない、ということですか？

---

> Also, seeing how most dogs in Japan are from pet shops, how would I explain that he is a rescue dog? I've seen 里親 used online to reference a person who adopts a dog, but how do I reference the dog?

I think "rescue(d) dog" is called [保護犬]{ほごけん}. (If it's not understood I think you could add that it was a [捨]{す}て[犬]{いぬ}, "abandoned dog".) So how about...

> 「この子は保護犬（or 捨て犬）だったんです。それで、里親として [[引]{ひ}き[取]{と}っ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%BC%95%E5%8F%96%E3%82%8B/)たんですよ or [[譲]{ゆず}り[受]{う}け](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%AD%B2%E3%82%8A%E5%8F%97%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B/#jn-225333)たんですよ。」
>   「保護犬（or 捨て犬）だったのを、引き取ったんですよ。」
>   「保護犬だったんですが、里親になったんですよ。」